# Date and time conversion using Pandas & Python to create Ts

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get Ts using my existing data of data and time, which looks like

```
(Pdb) df[0][:7] 
0    [Data & Time]
1     Jan 01 08:00:01.193
2     Jan 01 08:00:01.275
3     Jan 01 08:00:01.294
4     Jan 01 08:00:01.335
5     Jan 01 08:00:01.357
6     Jan 01 08:00:01.392
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

So using above data, I'm planning to insert another column 'Ts' with value  like `df[0][i] - df[0][i-1]`.

so the plan is

1. split data into two column `Jan 01 08:00:01.193` -> `01/01` `08:00:01.193`
2. insert new column 'Ts', makes 3 columns in total.

I'm looking into regex to split columns, but I'm wondering if it's possible to access and execute split all data without using for loop? I've learned little about vectorization, but I cannot imagine how to with integration of regex...?

Comment: You say you're "trying to get `Ts`"... what is `Ts`? Please explain what you're trying to do, not how you think it can be done.

Comment: `df[0][i] - df[0][i-1]` almost looks like you want to subtract the date above for each row?

Comment: Your data seems messed up, why is the row value at index 0 `[Data & Time]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Given a properly formatted DataFrame*:

```
             timestamp
0  Jan 01 08:00:01.193
1  Jan 01 08:00:01.275
2  Jan 01 08:00:01.294
3  Jan 01 08:00:01.335
4  Jan 01 08:00:01.357
5  Jan 01 08:00:01.392
```

We can first convert it to `datetime`:

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format='%b %d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Then make the two new columns:

```
df['day/month'] = df.timestamp.dt.strftime('%d/%m')
df['time'] = df.timestamp.dt.time
```

Output:

```
                timestamp day/month             time
0 1900-01-01 08:00:01.193     01/01  08:00:01.193000
1 1900-01-01 08:00:01.275     01/01  08:00:01.275000
2 1900-01-01 08:00:01.294     01/01  08:00:01.294000
3 1900-01-01 08:00:01.335     01/01  08:00:01.335000
4 1900-01-01 08:00:01.357     01/01  08:00:01.357000
5 1900-01-01 08:00:01.392     01/01  08:00:01.392000
```

Edit:

By the way, this isn't regex. They're [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: Just the answer I was about to submit!

Comment: I've tried regex to split each string of data but ended up using strftime() as well.Thank you for the easy/clean answer!